# How do I configure ColdFusion Model Glue 3 so that it won't redirect on AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an event-handler, configured like so:

```
<event-handler name="action.product.delete">
    <broadcasts>
        <message="DeleteProduct"/>
    </broadcasts>
    <results>
        <result do="page.product.list" redirect="true"/>
    </results>
</event-handler>
```

In other words, delete the product, then redirect the user to back to the products list. This event will be called from another event called `page.product.delete`, which shows a delete confirmation page.

Now I'm trying to use the remoting service that was introduced in Model Glue 3. I try to send an AJAX POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'RemotingService.cfc?method=executeevent&requestformat=json',
    data: {
        id: productId,
        eventName: 'action.iat.delete',
        returnValues: 'message'
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Although this works fine in terms of deleting the product, what ends up happening is that the browser will send one **POST** request, receive a 302 Redirect, and then do a **GET** request immediately afterwards. The **GET** request is the HTML page and not JSON data.

If I remove the `redirect="true"` from the event-handler, the AJAX will work correctly, but the generated URL from the non-AJAX version of my page will not. What will end up happening is that the user will perform a delete and confirm it, and the `action.product.delete` page will show them the `page.product.list` page, but not change the URL. If the user bookmarks this page, they will be bookmarking`action.product.delete`!

How do I configure my application so that both will work properly, or will I have to go back to using remote procedure calls on CFCs to handle my AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The **requestFormat** variable you are already using is special in that it can be used as a filter for broadcasts, views, and results within a Model-Glue 3 event handler. The default value for requestFormat is `html`, so if you specify it for your handler's result block the results in it will be skipped for your json requests:

```
<event-handler name="action.product.delete">
    <broadcasts>
        <message="DeleteProduct"/>
    </broadcasts>
    <results format="html">
        <result do="page.product.list" redirect="true"/>
    </results>
</event-handler>
```

If you need a different result to be processed for your json requests, just add a `<results format="json">...</results>` block in your event handler. Model-Glue 3 allows multiple broadcasts, views, and results blocks per event handler.

For more information check out the [Formats](http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki/HowTos/HowToUseFormats) page on the [Model-Glue wiki](http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki).

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is that, when sending an AJAX request, make sure to append `requestformat=json` (or any other request format) to the querystring. Otherwise it will default to HTML, even for AJAX requests.